# Changing color of points based on increasing or decreasing values

Tags: r, if-statement, plot

in Plots I am trying to use pch= ifelse but I am unsure how to test the condition.

```
x=1:10
y=c(1,5,3,2,1,10,6,5,3,8)
plot(x,y,pch=for(i in 1:10){ifelse(y[i+1]<y[i],8,0)})
```

I want to change the shape (or color) of the points based on them being increasing or decreasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first point uses `pch = 1`:

```
plot(x, y, pch = c(1, ifelse(y[-1] < y[-length(y)], 8, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is great. So y[-1] is excluding the first point and  ifelse knows to move through the entire vector?

Comment: Indeed. It checks the condition element-wise.